# CKeditor file browser JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, syntax-error

In my PHP browsefile when result back I have JavaScript error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

code :

```
 $result ="
                   <a onclick='window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('$funcNum', '$url', '$message')'>
                   <img src='$url'  style='width:200px; height=200px; float right; padding 20px; background-color:#CCC; border:3px solid #CCC;'  />
                   </a>
                   ";
                   echo $result;
```

When I click on image to add in CKeditor i have Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

and there is ckeditor config :

```
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
        language: 'de',
        uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
        skin: 'bootstrapck',
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/content/tab:filelist',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/content/tab:file',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'content/tab:imagelist',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'content/tab:uploadimage'

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra } somewhere. You can use  http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php to verify your javascript.

Comment: First count the number of  { and }. You should be able to figure it out.

Comment: that's equal ! both { and }